# Azure Functions Resize blob with two output blobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, outputstream

I have an Azure function which resizes an image, and then saves to another container folder.

My code is;

```
private static readonly Dictionary<ImageSize, Tuple<int, int>> ImageDimensionsTable = new Dictionary<ImageSize, Tuple<int, int>>()
{
    { ImageSize.ExtraSmall, Tuple.Create(320, 200) },
    { ImageSize.Small,      Tuple.Create(640, 400) },
    { ImageSize.Medium,     Tuple.Create(800, 600) }
};

private enum ImageSize
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The extra small
    /// </summary>
    ExtraSmall,

    /// <summary>
    /// The small
    /// </summary>
    Small,

    /// <summary>
    /// The medium
    /// </summary>
    Medium
}

[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static void Run(
    [BlobTrigger("vehicle-images/{folder}/{name}", Connection = "")]Stream image,
    string name,
    [Blob("watermarked-vehicle-images/{folder}/s-{name}", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection = "")]CloudBlockBlob imageSmall,
    [Blob("watermarked-vehicle-images/{folder}/m-{name}", FileAccess.ReadWrite, Connection = "")]CloudBlockBlob imageMedium,
    TraceWriter log)
{
    // Resize and save Small Image
    var size = ImageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Small];
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    var instructions = new Instructions
    {
        Width = size.Item1,
        Height = size.Item2,
        Mode = FitMode.Max,
        OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Jpeg,
        JpegQuality = 85
    };

    ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(image, outputStream, instructions));
    outputStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    imageSmall.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    imageSmall.UploadFromStream(outputStream);

    // Resize and save Medium Image.
    size = ImageDimensionsTable[ImageSize.Medium];    

    var outputStream2 = new MemoryStream();
    var instructions2 = new Instructions
    {
        Width = size.Item1,
        Height = size.Item2,
        Mode = FitMode.Max,
        OutputFormat = OutputFormat.Jpeg,
        JpegQuality = 85
    };

    ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(image, outputStream2, instructions2));
    outputStream2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    imageMedium.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    imageMedium.UploadFromStream(outputStream2);

}
```

So what this is currently doing is triggering for an image upload, going through the first step of resizing to the small size, but then when it gets to the code to resize to the Medium size, it is giving an error `Error: my-vehicle-image.jpg Parameter is not valid.`

So what I suspect is that the my original `Stream image` is being closed? or disposed of, so that when I get to trying to use `ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(image, outputStream2, instructions2));` this is not valid?

Hopefully this is something easy to fix. My alternative, and it works, is to have 2 functions with one resizing the small, and one resizing the large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so discovered that `ImageJob` has an overload which accepts `bool disposeSource`, so I have updated my code to be;

`ImageBuilder.Current.Build(new ImageJob(image, outputStream, instructions, false, false));`

This way the second time I want to use `image` it is still available to me.

Answer (score 1):

For scaling and other purposes I would recommend two functions. To seek the source stream after the first resize could be a problem depending on the binding and technology you use for the input stream.

Personally I created a similar solution where I read the source stream first to a MemoryStream and than performing several operations on the MemoryStream decoupling the source stream abilities (seeking etc.).

That maybe increases your memory footprint which you can try to again minimize by solutions like the RecyclableMemoryStream (https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. For now I have managed to figure out how to use my existing code, but will keep in mind separating out. There is another layer of complexity to come with what I am trying to achieve, so keeping in one method might be the only way to do it for now.

Comment: Sounds good. Consider to pool or recycle your 'outputStream' in order to reduce the memory footprint of your function app.